# Passing params to another controller in Rails administrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, administrate, rails-administrate

This would seem to be a fairly straightforward question but I couldn't seem to find anything about it in the docs.  I have a model `events` which `has_many` nested `performances` (which has an `event_id`).  Now I could use something like:

https://github.com/nickcharlton/administrate-field-nested_has_many

But it had a bunch of jquery dependencies as it uses cocoon and it just seemed like too much work for my use case.  I would just like to send one param, the `event_id` onto the nested controller so that it's value is prefilled but by default, this doesn't seem to work.

eg I just want to provide a link like so: `/admin/performances/new?performance_event_id=751`

And then have the select field selected.

It seems like an easy thing to do but I couldn't find anything in the documentation short of creating my own custom field to overwrite the default `has_many` field so that it will look for a param value?  Or if I should add something into the controller to set this on the new action?

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. When you say "another" controller, you mean "another" from what exactly? This link you want to provide with the query string, where do you want to show this link? Can you describe a step-by-step use case so that we can tell more precisely what you intend to implement? I get the impression that you may want to override [`Administrate::ApplicationController#new_resource`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/f8c0d71110ca39253ef0c92f554b7e8e6a42e314/app/controllers/administrate/application_controller.rb#L214) but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The gem is made to be simple stupid, so it does not support these kind of functionalities. It is as you say, if you want to send custom params you either need to create a customized field, use JS or create a custom controller action. In the documentation they recommend to use custom fields, ref: https://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/adding_custom_field_types